# Implement a collection view SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I implement a collection view (that is,  rectangles arranged in a grid) in SwiftUI?

I've tried ForEach-ing over a range of values, then using the counter as an index for an Array but have had numerous problems so are looking for a different way to achieve a collection view.

The cells to wrap over multiple rows. I have a `SegmentedControl` which is used to set how many cells to squeeze on one row.

Here is what I have:

```
VStack { // Multiple rows
    ForEach((0..<requiredRows).identified(by: \.self)) { row in // Iterate over (previously calculated) required row count
        HStack(spacing: 50)) { // Row
            ForEach((0..<self.maximumOnXAxis).identified(by: \.self)) { cell in // Iterate over available cells
                MyView(
                    width: calculatedSize,
                    height: calculatedSize / 2.0,
                    colour: Color(
                        red: lst[row * self.maximumOnXAxis][0],
                        green: lst[row * self.maximumOnXAxis][1],
                        blue: lst[row * self.maximumOnXAxis][2]
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

And all of the above is inside a ScrollView.

The current problem is a 'Could not type check in reasonable time ...', which happened after I add the `colour: Colour(...)` parameter to `MyView`.

Example of desired effect:
[image: Collection View Example]

Comment: Post the code you've already tried. Additionally, a picture of the square grid you're trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: Apple has yet to add a grid or arbitrary layout like ColelctionView for SwiftUI.  You can use `UIViewRepresentable` to embed a collectionView in a SwiftUI.View. There is a whole tutorial on it here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Comment: Do you want to have a set number of columns in this grid? Or do you have a set frame for each item?

Comment: Provide your "MyView" View's code! So that we can get better idea about your issue.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827148/how-to-create-grid-in-swiftui It will help you!!

Answer (score 3):

SwiftUI does support a `ScrollView` which you can use to present collections, although you would have to manage your own grids. The `GeometryReader` method might be helpful, it allows you to easily scale the "cells" to the width and length of the parent view.

For reference, I've created a simple horizontal scroll view. You can use this same logic to create a grid view:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct MyView : View {

    let items: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    var body : some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                  ForEach(self.items.identified(by: \.self)) { row in
                    Text(row)
                        .padding(geometry.size.width / 5)
                        .background(Color.green)
                  }
                }
            }.background(Color.white)

        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
    }

}

let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: MyView())
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm doing this already. My fault, see edited question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for : https://github.com/pietropizzi/GridStack

The only missing feature is that you cannot do "masonry" like layout