# How to create grid in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I know that we can create a List in vertical SwiftUI like this,

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but is there any way that we could split the list in 2 or 3 or maybe more spans that covers the screen like a grid like we did in `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your customView like this to achieve UICollectionView behavior:-

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            ScrollView(showsHorizontalIndicator: true) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0...10) {_ in
                        GridView()
                    }
                }
            }
            List {
                ForEach(0...5) {_ in
                    ListView()
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ListView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        .color(.red)
    }
}

struct GridView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Image("marker")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .frame(height: 200)
                .border(Color.red)
            Text("test")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: will it support resusablity

Answer (score 5):

Checkout ZStack based example [here](https://github.com/spacenation/grid)

```
Grid(0...100) { _ in
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## iOS 14

There is 2 new native `View`s that you can use:

1. `LazyHGrid` [image: HGrid]
2. `LazyVGrid` [image: VGrid]

With code or directly from the library:

[image: Preview]

The library contains a fully working sample code that you can test yourself.

Comment: This should be the right answer! `LazyHGrid` is probably what you want in your case. There’s a great intro to this on Hacking with Swift: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-position-views-in-a-grid-using-lazyvgrid-and-lazyhgrid

Answer (score 2):

Available for **iOS/iPadOS 14 on Xcode 12**. You can use LazyVGrid to load just what the user see into screen and not the whole list, **List** is lazy by default.

```
import SwiftUI

//MARK: - Adaptive
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum:100))]) {
                ForEach(yourObjects) { object in
                    YourObjectView(item: object)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Custom Columns
struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
         ScrollView {   
             LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 4)) {
                 ForEach(yourObjects) { object in
                     YourObjectView(item: object)
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Don't forget replace the info **objects** with your info and **YourObjectView** with your **customView**.