# SwiftUI: ScrollView pagingEnabled no longer working on iOS 16.4

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, swiftui-scrollview

On iOS 16.3 the `ScrollView` component can enable paging by setting the following:

```
UIScrollView.appearance().isPagingEnabled = true
```

However, after updating to iOS 16.4, this no longer enables paging on the `ScrollView`. Are there any workarounds to make this solution work? or are there alternative ways to build vertical paging in SwiftUI? I'm familiar with workarounds using `TabView` but I cannot use that in this project for other reasons.

Comment: Have you tried setting the property directly on the scrollview instance rather than on all scrollviews via the appearance proxy?

Comment: @Paulw11 SwiftUI's `ScrollView` does not have a `isPagingEnabled` property

Comment: Sorry, I missed the SwiftUI reference. I guess it was an undocumented effect that no longer works.

Comment: There might be some solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893240/is-there-any-way-to-make-a-paged-scrollview-in-swiftui ?

Comment: @John I'm seeing the problem on simulators running 16.4, but not devices running 16.5 (and there is no simulator for 16.5). Were you able to confirm this problem exists on devices running 16.4, and not just the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

##### Horizontal/Vertical paging in iOS 17

From **iOS 17**, you don't need to tweak the UIKit appearance. All you need to do is applying the following modifier on the `ScrollView`:

```
.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
```

This works on both `horizontal` and `vertical` scrollViews

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CollectionView wrapper.
you can follow this [link](https://github.com/ShivadityaKr/CollectionViewSwiftUI) already implemented.