# Text not appearing but onAppear triggers

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to use forEach in HStack and VStack. I am using Text in them and Text is not appearing while running but onAppear print values. Please have a look on my code. Why Text is not appearing? How can I make this work?

```
@State var sd = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]

VStack {
    ForEach(0...sd.count/3) { _ in
        HStack {
            ForEach(0...2) { _ in
                if(self.sd.isEmpty) {
                } else {
                    Text("Test")
                        .onAppear() {
                            if(!self.sd.isEmpty) {
                                print("i appeared")
                                self.sd.removeFirst()
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here?

I am trying to create a HStacks with maximum 3 Texts in it. I am using array here only to rendered Text 7 times.

Expected result with array with 7 elements--->

Want to create a VStack of 3 HStacks, In first 2 HStacks I want to render Text 3 times and in last HStack I want only one Text. (Like I have 7 array elements that's why 3 texts in first two hstacks and one in last hstack). If array has 10 elements, then 3 Hstacks of 3 Texts and last Stack with 1 Text. I am unable to render Text because my array is @state var and it refresh view.body every time I remove firstElement from it.

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour I am trying to achieve by using SwiftUI only. I don't want to use UICollection view.

Comment: Three quick questions. (1) How many times is "i appeared" executing? (2) What are you trying to do with the nested `ForEach` loops? But mostly, (3) What is your expected output?

Comment: 1) Seven times. 2) I am trying to get 3 hstacks (first two with 3 texts and third with 2 texts). 3) 3 hstacks (first two with 3 texts and third with 2 texts).

Comment: Not to sound critical, but your array only has seven values. :-) More, you are treating a one-dimensional array like a two-dimensional one. (Usually inner loops work on a second dimension.) Sorry for repeating, but 3 `Stacks` containing 3, 3, and 2 `Texts`. What values?

Comment: Yes my main question is that its printing "I appeared" but Texts are not visible in view. Answer below clarifies that why nothing is rendered. But I want to achieve 3 3 2 Hstacks. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe, the problem is you're being too vague for me to help. From your comment to the answer, I'm wondering if it might help me if you talk in terms of `UIKit`. (I'm thinking your problem is with what Apple introduced last month but maybe it's deeper. Again - but this time *specifically* - what should *each* "stack" show? (It might be easier to show that in your question - formatting comments is rather poor.) Given your array of seven values, how should they be rendered?

Comment: please have check edited question. It may help you to understand it in better way.

Comment: Are you trying to create a grid? if so, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827148/how-to-create-grid-in-swiftui or maybe this https://medium.com/@azamsharp/building-grid-layout-in-swiftui-bcd3bc9627af

Comment: Sorry but you are not getting this. I am not trying to create a normal grid. I want a way by which last row of grid may not have same number of elements. First two rows(Hstacks) -> 3 elements. Last row(Hstack) -> 1 element. Please read edited description

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't want to change a @State variable as a side-effect of the evaluation of `body`; in this case, your `self.sd.removeFirst()` is causing the `body` to be marked as needing to be re-evaluated, so `SwiftUI` just keeps calling it until your `sd` array is empty, which is why you don't see anything being rendered.

To get the effect you want, this is one way you can do it:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var sd = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
    private let columns = 3

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: sd.count, by: columns))) { row in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<self.columns) { col in
                        if row + col < self.sd.count {
                            Text("\(self.sd[row + col])")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Most attempts to modify state within the `body` evaluation seem to result in the runtime warning `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.` – it seems that your array mutation somehow side-stepped this check, but hopefully that sort of thing will be called out at runtime in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to learn more about state I guess. Is there any way to achieve the behaviour I am trying to achieve?

Comment: What exactly is the desired behavior?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that I want to create a VStack of 3 HStacks, In first 2 HStacks I want to render Text 3 times and in last HStack I want only one Text. (Like I have 7 array elements that's why 3 texts in first two hstacks and one in last hstack). If array has 10 elements, then 3 Hstacks of 3 Texts and last Stack with 1 Text.

Comment: I've updated the answer in response to the updated question.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: @Lalli If you’re happy with this answer, you should accept it.

Comment: Maybe `LazyVGrid` can work better in this situation?